# How to use np.append when the existing array is in 2d with 25 values and the value to append only contain 1 value?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to add one value to 'current_batch' array which in 2d shape with 25 data values. Below is the coding that I refer to a tutorial video in youtube, which is used np.append() to combined the 2d array and 1d array with same data values. However, mine is a little different because the value to append is in 1d array with only one values. How should I changes the coding to append the values?

This is the coding:

```
import numpy as np

predictions = []

first_batch = train[-n_input:] #take last 5 rows into predictions array

current_batch = first_batch.reshape((1, n_input, n_features))

# print(first_batch)
for i in range(len(test)):

  # get the prediction value for the first batch
  current_pred = model.predict(current_batch)[0]

  # print(current_pred)
  # append the prediction into the array
  predictions.append(current_pred)

  # remove the first value
  current_batch_rmv_first = current_batch[:, 1:, :]
  
  # update the batch
  current_batch = np.append(current_batch_rmv_first, [[current_pred]], axis=1) 

print(current_batch)
```

Example of data in array

- current_batch & current_batch_rmv_first:

```
[[a1,b1,c1,...,d1,e1]
 [a2,b2,c2,...,d2,e2]
 [a3,b3,c3,...,d3,e3]
 [a4,b4,c4,...,d4,e4]
 [a5,b5,c5,...,d5,e5]]
```

- current_pred = [f]

Comment: That code shouldn't be using np.append.  `current_batch` should be a list, and use list append.

Comment: @hpaulj Do you mean like this "current_batch = current_batch_rmv_first.append(current_pred) "

Comment: you are already collecting results in the `predictions` list.  What are you trying to do with `curent_batch`?